# 301 redirect on IBM WCM

Tags: content-management-system, http-status-code-301, wcm

On IBMs Web Content Management System how can I setup a 301 redirect, I can't seem to find any information on how to do this. The version of WCM the site is running is 6.0.1.4

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this at the front http server level.

Answer (score 0):

Either edit your HTTP Server configuration to peform a RewriteRule, or add the following to an Element (called Redirect) on your Content item:
http://newserver.com/newpage.html" />

In your Presentation Template add: [Element type="content" context="current" key="Redirect"]